# Initializing semaphore statically at compile-time?

Tags: linux-kernel

I've been trying to follow some syntax from Love's Linux Kernel Development, but having some difficulty in the following simplified semaphore initialization. I keep getting a "error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token' during kernel compilation. This makes it sound like it's treating my sema_init() call as a function prototype, when its really just a static inline function call.

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/pstrace.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>

struct semaphore sem1;
int count1 = 3;
sema_init(&sem1,count1);

SYSCALL_DEFINE0(helloworld){
    extern struct semaphore sem1;

    printk("hello, world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts on how else to do this? (I know I'm not actually using the semaphore in the call.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t call a function outside a function in this way. To initialise your semaphore, use an `__init` function:

```c
static int __init helloworld_init(void) {
        sema_init(&sem1, 3);

        return 0;
}

module_init(helloworld_init);
```

You’ll need to `#include <linux/module.h>` too.

(Yes, this looks like self-contradicting advice since `module_init()` appears to be called outside a function, but `sema_init()` is a function, and `module_init()` is a macro.)

Comment: Thank you! was under the mistaken vague impression from LKD that sema_init() being an inline function that calls a macro meant it could be called outside a function.   

Is there a way to initialize these semaphores at compile-time, the way we can with mutexes? I was wondering if I could avoid having a wrapper function just to initialize the semaphore before my actual timing-sensitive code runs.